# Drupal search result page loads forever - 80% CPU

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

As already mentioned, the page result takes forever to load. Long enough to trigger a timeout on bad days.
I have checked htop and seen that the php process takes up to 80-85% of the server's CPU.

I have checked, disabled and evaluated the following:

- Same result with or without Facet Api
- Same result with or without Caching
- MySQL queries are ok (in terms of drupal...)
- The search result tpl is not responsible (I tried removing everything frm the tpl excet "print 'test'", it still took forever)
- there are no php errors in recent log messages, none in apache logs
- The Solr server is absolutely bored and returns the 70 results in half a blink of an eye

Where can I look? How could I debug this stuff? I'm thankful for any advice!

Comment: Do you have any custom modules developed for this project? If you disable all custom modules does it solves the problem? Had seen similar issue before from a custom module using hook_field_access and it was killing the site.

Comment: @St0iK thanks for the hint! We decided to revert to the last working version but I'll remember that for the next time!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a profiling tool like XDebug or Blackfire.io (the latter is my favorite). It'll map out which functions are called for that page and which functions / modules / hook are responsible for the excessive load.

Comment: Thank you for helping! We decided to go back to the last working version but this will help for the next time!